# Pandas groupby multiple columns take average of another based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, transform

I'm stuck on this and similar posts are creating a bit of a black hole for me. I'm still learning..

I would like to take the mean of a group that meets a condition. My data looks like this:

```
user          date           Flag    Value  
0    ron  12/23/2016        'flag'    10     
1    ron  12/21/2016        'n/a'     25     
2    ron   12/23/2016       'flag'    10     
3    ron  12/21/2016        'n/a'     3      
4   andy   12/22/2016       'flag'    5      
5   andy   12/22/2016       'flag'    1
```

I'd like to groupby user + Flag and create a new column 'Avg' that takes only the Avg values of 'flag'. So the data would look like this:

```
user          date           Flag    Value  Avg
0    ron  12/23/2016        'flag'    10     10
1    ron  12/21/2016        'n/a'     25     10
2    ron   12/23/2016       'flag'    10     10
3    ron  12/21/2016        'n/a'     3      10
4   andy   12/22/2016       'flag'    5      3
5   andy   12/22/2016       'flag'    1      3
```

I have something like this, but have tried many different variations:

```
groups = sample.groupby(['user','Flag'])
flag = sample.groupby(['user','Flag'])['Value'].transform('mean')
sample.loc[:,'Avg'] = np.select([flag.eq('flag'), groups.transform('mean')])
```

Guidance is appreciated..

Comment: Just `sample['Avg'] = sample.groupby(['user','Flag'])['Value'].transform('mean')`? Although I'm not sure why the second row is `10`.

Comment: almost, but I'd like to populate Avg with the same value per user regardless of Flag==flag or Flag==n/a. So where Flag==flag take the mean(Value) and populate that. That's why I'm trying out the np.select above @QuangHoang

Comment: Because it is by user, so for user 'ron' there is a 'flag' value for row 1 and row 3, so take mean of 10+10 and that becomes the value for the user

Comment: I mean row `3`, which is also `ron` but has value 3?

Comment: right, so only take average of Value where Flag == 'flag' and that is the Avg for the user

Comment: But the mean for `ron` is `10` not `3`. Why row 3 (last `ron`'s row) has `Avg==3`?

Comment: very sorry you are right, i have corrected that...i made a typo in the mockup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution with `groupby` and `map`:

```
df['Avg'] = df['user'].map(df[df['Flag']=="'flag'"]            # use "flag" only if you don't have `'` in the data'
                             .groupby('user')['Value'].mean())
```

Output:

```
   user        date    Flag  Value  Avg
0   ron  12/23/2016  'flag'     10   10
1   ron  12/21/2016   'n/a'     25   10
2   ron  12/23/2016  'flag'     10   10
3   ron  12/21/2016   'n/a'      3   10
4  andy  12/22/2016  'flag'      5    3
5  andy  12/22/2016  'flag'      1    3
```

Comment: awesome thank you! map function seems much easier , I understand this